# Assigning external stylesheet to specific table in html

Tags: html, css

Can I assign an external css stylesheet for a specific table out of many in a single page ?

Comment: You should add your code to enable others to properly guide you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can do it. However using more than one style-sheets is not good from a performance perspective. If you know that you are NEVER going to change your CSS code  once you have built it then single style-sheet is best for you. Multiple style-sheet are good if you are going to change your CSS once in while and you need to keep it easily manageable/updateable.

**To assign external stylesheet to a specific table:**

1.First assign a css class name or css id name (for example I am using class name "table-with-external-SS") to your table in your html page code as below:

```
<table class="table-with-external-SS">
<thead>
..............
..............
..............
</table>
```

2.Then create an external stylesheet which target only this table's class.Write css to target only the table with class for e.g. ".table-with-external-SS" as following:

```
table.table-with-external-SS {
    color: navy;
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

3.Save this by any name for example mystylesheet.css. Then link this stylesheet in you html code in head section as below:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystylesheet.css">
</head>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**style.css**

```
#someid{
    color: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

...

<table id="someid">
    ...
</table>
```